# the reason for me + (gerund) / (infinitve)

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, gerund-phrases

> The reason to go abroad is to study.
>
> The reason for me going abroad is to study.

These two examples sound correct to me.it popped into my mind that if the following expression would be correct.

> The reason for me to go abroad is to study.

As a native speaker , do you think it sounds correct? 
If so , what is its difference from the first sentence above in meaning?

Comment: They are all okay, but it would be more natural to say _My reason for going abroad is to study_. By the way, are you from Turkey?

Comment: @BillJ .Yes Turkey.

Comment: I'd say the second alternative sounds clunky, and would always use @BillJ's suggestion instead.

Answer (score -1):

Acually, there is no difference in meaning between number two and number 3. English learners use different ways in speaking and writing. But in both number two and number three are different from number one in meaning. Number one refers to general reason that the speaker thinks yet number two and three refers to only the speaker's reason. Hope this can help.